# Simple level system

Tags: python, pygame

I would leave to great a simple level system. When the score Variable reaches a certain number it would increase enemies (balls) & velocity(Speed) for example:

```
if score >= 500:
   enemies=6
   velocity=2
```

I have tried few methods, the my first attempt was like the above within my game loop but I wasn't able to change it on the fly, Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\MO\Desktop\Twerk\ballbounce_changed.py", line 233, in <module>
  game()
File "C:\Users\MO\Desktop\Twerk\ballbounce_changed.py", line 182, in game
 positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have also tried other methods which didn't work. can you please help me implement a level system. My game code can found here: http://pastebin.com/nhqKdR19

Thank you

Comment: (Not looking at the pastebin:) Your implementation and your error seem *radically* divergent.  Check the dimensions of `positionx` and `positionxmove` and see if they're equivalent before you can attempt something like that.

Comment: Just taking a look at your source code, you really need to start using classes. Having many lists storing indexed data isn't natural and will cause errors. Try using classes for entities in your game.

Comment: Also, you should probably avoid `if score == 500` and use `if score >= 500` as well.  When you use equal, your difficulty will never ratchet up unless the user hits exactly 500 points at the end of a game loop.  What you want is to ratchet it up once the user has gotten 500 or more points.

Comment: how can modify my tracking list?, not sure what I need increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if score == 500:
    enemies = 6
    velocity = 2
```

You should probably have an `increase_difficulty()` method that modifies your tracking lists and increases the `velocity` value.  You should also be using `>=` instead of `==` as I mentioned above.  Then your game loop code would be:

```
if score >= 500:
    increase_difficulty()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code initially starts out with those lists having 3 elements, then you bump up your enemies count to 6 without extending the lists.  This causes your update loop to run off the end of the list as it tries to update past the end of your lists.  When you increase enemies, you need to also append new values to your lists to expand them by 3 more entries.  To extend an already existing list, use [`name_of_your_list.append(new_value)`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: How can I increase the list size on the fly, sorry I have no idea.